# If a iPhone user has disabled "Set Automatically" for time zones, is it still possible to find the current local one?

Tags: ios, iphone, timezone, nstimezone

The scenario is a iPhone user who doesn't want the time to automatically update when he travels abroad and thus has disabled the system setting "Set Automatically" for time zones, leading to `[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]` not updating for his new location.

As a developer, can I still find out the current local time and time zone for the (possibly new) country the device is in?

Comment: you may ask his/her current location and based on this result find out where he/she is and what's the current time there

Comment: I think this is bad design. The user has elected not to update his timezone, which means you should display data in the timezone of the user. Adding location services to your application only for this reason alone sounds very pervasive and most users would select "NO", so you would end up with no real location anyway.

Comment: The app in question is a Time Zone Converter, so I thought it would be nice for it to automatically detect if the user had moved to a new time zone, hence the question... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not without some work anyway, and maybe not with some work.

If the user has disabled auto time zone setting, the only time zone you get to know about is the one that they've told their phone to use. You don't get to bypass their preferences on that. Unfortunately you also don't get to find out if they've done that. All you get is a time zone, but why that's current is not something you can answer.

If you're determined, you might try using Core Location to get their latitude and longitude, and work out a time zone from that. Doing that reliably may be a challenge-- the official [IANA time zone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) includes lat/long, but only at one location within each time zone. There are services like [AskGeo](http://askgeo.com) that claim to solve this problem (they might be fantastic, I haven't tried them). But that obviously requires a network connection, and people traveling to other countries are probably less likely than average to have mobile data access.